# Get more than one custom object

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get a different custom object for the amount of Ports (in a NIC) that are on a server.

The below script  **only captures the last Port that it processed**. How can I create a custom object for however many Ports are on a server? Some might have 2 and others 4 etc. Ideally then save each object with a name I can then use later:

```
$objects = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapter -filter "Name LIKE '%Intel%' OR Name LIKE '%HP%' OR Name LIKE '%Broadcom%'"

Foreach($object in $objects){
    $object = New-Object –TypeNamePSObject
    $object | Add-Member –MemberTypeNoteProperty –Name NetEnabled –Value $os.NetEnabled
    $object | Add-Member –MemberTypeNoteProperty –Name PNPDeviceID –Value $os.PNPDeviceID
    Write-Output $object
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overwriting the current `object` within your `foreach` loop and use a variable `$os` which is not defined.

You probably want to do something like this:

```
Foreach($os in $objects)
{
    $object = New-Object –TypeNamePSObject
    $object | Add-Member –MemberTypeNoteProperty –Name NetEnabled –Value $os.NetEnabled
    $object | Add-Member –MemberTypeNoteProperty –Name PNPDeviceID –Value $os.PNPDeviceID
    Write-Output $object
}
```

However, since you only selecting two properties, you could do this instead:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapter -filter "Name LIKE '%Intel%' OR Name LIKE '%HP%' OR Name LIKE '%Broadcom%'" | 
   select NetEnabled, PNPDeviceID
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is currently equivalent to

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapter |
  where Name -match 'Intel|HP|Broadcom' |
  foreach {
    $os | select NetEnabled,PNPDeviceID
  }
```

(assuming a few spaces in the right places to make it run at all).

This essentially makes no sense at all. Maybe you mean something more akin to the following?

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapter |
  where Name -match 'Intel|HP|Broadcom' |
  select NetEnabled,PNPDeviceID
```

Note that due to your re-assignment to `$object` in the loop and the usage of `$os` you *don't use anything from the queried objects at all*.